# ImageView is not getting refreshed with AsyncTask fetching images from URL

Tags: android, android-imageview, google-maps-android-api-2, marker, android-handler

I am trying to play a video like animation in the google maps - marker's infoWindow.
Following are the things that work perfectly :

1. Able to show Image slide show (stored in the res/drawable folder) inside the markers infoWindow using a handler that updates the UI image view inside the Marker's infoWindow
2. I also got the video server up and running that serves the Image Bitmaps as Streams when requested
3. I also developed a mobile client that fetches the video(series of images) from the server and play that as a video.

Now, from the APPLICATION [1] i developed, Instead of the stored images, I am trying to Fetch series of images(that belongs to the video) from SERVER [2] and set the received images in the imageView.

The problem I am facing is I am getting new images and I am calling the imageView.setImageBitmap(bt); but the imageView is not getting refreshed until I force the view to be updated (via touch events)

Below is my code :

```
class RefreshHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        BasicMapActivity.this.updateUI();
    }

    public void sleep(long delayMillis) {
        this.removeMessages(0);
        sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), delayMillis);
    }
};


public void updateUI() {

    refreshHandler.sleep(200); // Handler type object which makes this function to call as if its on a different thread

    Log.d("Update UI - in RUN", "liveOffset : " + liveOffset);

    StreamElement se = getNextLiveView();

    if (se != null) {
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(se.getData(), 0, se.getData().length);
        Bitmap bt=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 150, 150, false);
        Log.d("Actual Refresh ", "liveOffset : " + liveOffset);  // updates inside the above getNextLiveView function that fetches the new image
imageViewK = (ImageView) kv.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageViewK.setImageBitmap(bt);  // Received new image is set every time on the imageView
        //imageViewK.postInvalidate();      
    } else{
        Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
        imgidK[1]);
        Bitmap bt = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap, 75, 75, false);
        imageViewK.setImageBitmap(bt);
    }
```

}

I have commented the above code to explain my situation. This is getting logged every time (Log.d("Actual Refresh ", "liveOffset : " + liveOffset) with updated liveOffset value) -> That means, I am able to reach the imageView setting line every time in the thread loop execution.  As you can see I have also tried using imageView.postInvalidate() as I imagine this method is running on a non-UI thread, but still the imageView is not getting updated automatically. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting something in the `ImageView` after getting it in your `if` condition?

Comment: @Apoorv : Sorry I have updated the code. My bad. Still its not working. Yeah that's the plan. If you look at the logcat line with tag "Actual Refresh ", its getting printed every time, which indicates that I am inside the 'if' condition. Else part is for the default image to be shown if server returns null.